# How to increase throttle limiit for an excel calc engine when using POI with Java?

Tags: java, performance, concurrency, apache-poi

We have a excel based calc engine that we read using POI and Java. As of now the throttle limit is approx 30-40 concurrent users. We want to increase this to 100. In current design we take user inputs and pass them to calc engine which does some very complex calculations and then we read the results from given cells from same workbook aka calc engine. 
What are the possible ways to increase the throttle limit for calc engine?
Can we have 2-3 copies of calc engine and redirect user to alternate calc work book? Will this increase performance?
Is there anything else we can do make performance better?

Comment: I suggest you try peerformance profiling your application.  You are likely to find all sorts of interesting bottlenecks.  The most obvious way to improve performance is to translate the spread sheet into Java, but if that is not an option, having multiple instances is likely to help.

Comment: I assume each sheet is single threaded, Is there any reason you cannot open the same sheet multiple times in the same engine so you can use multiple CPUs.  I assume your server is lightly loaded and you have the fastest CPU you can buy?? ;)

Comment: We used 2 copies of calc engine and redirect user to alternate calc work book - this worked for us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We used 2 copies of calc engine and redirect user to alternate calc work book - this worked for us.